# Boolean Index using Date Ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes. df has the columns `['Day', 'Account', 'Impressions', 'Views', 'Cost', 'Store Visits']`, and df1 has the columns `['Campaign', 'CID', 'Account', 'DMA', 'Start', 'End']`.

I am trying to create a new column in df that assigns the campaign value from df1 where Account values are equal and the Day in df is in between the Start and End for df1.

`df['Day']` and `df1[['Start','End']]` are all datetime values.

Here is what I have tried:

```
df['Campaign'] = df1['Campaign'][(df['Account'] == df['Account']) & (df['Day'] >= df1['Start']) & (df['Day'] <= df1['End'])]
```

but this error is being raised:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Would very much appreciate some help with this one.

Comment: do the `df` and `df1` have same `shape` ??

Comment: No, df1 is designed to be a lookup table.

Comment: Assuming `Account` has unique values in `df1` then you have to merge with `df` and then filter the data with the `date` condition. `mdf = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on='Account', right_on='Account', how='inner'); bad_date = ~((mdf['Day'] >= mdf['Start']) & (mdf['Day'] <= mdf['End'])); mdf[bad_date] = np.nan; mdf.dropna(how='all', axis=0, inplace=True);`